# How many threads are there in a simple GUI app?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, wxpython

I noticed that some `Exceptions` are caught normally by the main thread `except:` at the end of this code, and some other aren't (`1/0` in `OnButton`). Why ?

Does this mean that `OnButton(self, evt)` is launched in another thread ?

**How many threads are involved in a simple GUI app with wxPython ?**

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Test", size=(300, 300))
        MyPanel(self)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        #1/0       here this line would be handled by the try/except below

    def OnButton(self, evt):
        1/0       # when you click on button, why isn't this handled by the exception hanlder?      

try:
    app = wx.App(False)
    MyFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
except Exception, e: 
    print 'Hello' + type(e).__name__
```

Comment: Great question.   It's very non-intuitive how this works, and I found that when I started typing what I thought was the answer, I couldn't describe it clearly, so I realised that I too don't understand it completely.  I guess you do know that you can catch the onButton exception with sys.excepthook, but that is not what you were asking, I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one thread involved in a simple GUI app with wxPython
Take a look at the following link.

[why you can't use a global exception handler wrapped around the call to the app object's MainLoop method](http://wiki.wxpython.org/C++%20&%20Python%20Sandwich)

Comment: Thank you for this link. In order to have an example in this SO topic, do you know a solution with code for handling the `1/0` by the `try/except` exception handler at the end of my example ?

Comment: In http://wiki.wxpython.org/C++%20&%20Python%20Sandwich, I see how to use `class ExceptionLogging` to log the exceptions, but is also possible to redirect these exceptions to the main try/except of the last 2 lines of my code ?

Comment: There is a discusion in the following link that suggests using sys.excepthook https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/IXFsH9vKQMQ